# hidden input field not displaying value attribute in IE using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two forms in VUE that each have a hidden field that based on page url will set the value of these fields and then in turn send the form to the correct database. It works fine in every browser but I see in IE11 the value attribute is not displaying on page load so both forms are going to the same database table in IE11. Any solutions for this? I initially had a v-model on the fields but then switched to binding the value for one way binding but the value attribute is still not showing

```
  <!--hidden field -->
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="hidden" id="enrollmentFormHidden" class="form-input" :value="formData.enrollmentForm">
        </div>
        <!--end: hidden field -->


   <!--hidden field -->
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="hidden" id="enrollmentFormHidden" class="form-input" :value="formData.enrollmentFax">
        </div>
        <!--end: hidden field -->




 created: function () {
    //fill in hidden field values based on url
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/enrollment-fax') > -1) {
      this.formData.enrollmentFax = 'enrollment-fax'   
    }

    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/enrollment-form') > -1) {
      this.formData.enrollmentForm = 'enrollment-form'
    }
  },
```

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if this code does not work in IE somehow. Of course, IE will be officially killed soon but this code should work. Maybe some lifecycles are not triggered properly. Could you maybe update the `formData` later on in the app? The conditional should be pretty much the same, with less HTML duplication.

Comment: @kissu My first thought was update form data later, but I ended up moving the code block to the mounted cycle and it worked in IE.